# jQuery expression for data-group

Tags: jquery

I am not understanding how to add below expression in my jQuery code.
I have `data-group` as below:

```
<a data-group="["john-cena"]" href='something.com'>
```

So I wanna add `data-group` using jQuery expression I have tried my below code its not working. It's giving me error

```
$('a[data-groups="'+'['+'"'+group+'"'+']'+'"').removeClass('hidden');
```

Can anybody help me with this please?

Comment: `data-group="["john-cena"]"` is an invalid syntax

Comment: Its a valid one please refer to http://acasaprogramming.ro/filterable-portfolio-with-shuffle-js-and-bootstrap-3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax should be

```
$("a").attr("data-groups", '["john-cena"]');
```

Which will result in

```
<a data-groups="["john-cena"]" href='something.com'>
```

And to read it again in jQuery, you can do this:

```
$('a[data-groups=\\[\\"'+ group +'\\"\\]]').removeClass('hidden');
```

Comment: http://acasaprogramming.ro/filterable-portfolio-with-shuffle-js-and-bootstrap-3/ go to html section and see

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere check it out now. Now with proper escape character which does return the intended element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change attribute `data-group="["john-cena"]"` to something like `data-group="john-cena"`
because your syntax is incorrect.

You have double quotes for every square bracket, but they don't "cover" the exact word between the bracket. You can notice that in highlighted syntax (*blue color for string values*).

Also, change next:

```
$('a[data-group="' + group + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
```

Comment: http://acasaprogramming.ro/filterable-portfolio-with-shuffle-js-and-bootstrap-3/ goto html section see the data groups

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere ok, then notice the sequence of quotes here: `data-groups='["futurama"]'`